# Can I access the session in a model and why is it so bad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was thinking I could do this in my User model:

```
def sign_in
    remember_token = self.generate_remember_token
    self.update_attributes remember_token: remember_token
    session[:remember_token] = remember_token
end
```

and then in a sessions controller do this:

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by email: session_params[:email]
    if @user && @user.authenticate session_params[:password]
        @user.sign_in
    end
end
```

To me, this seems nice, clean and tidy. It seems DRY, thins out the controller and fattens up the model.

However this code doesn't work because I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<User:0x00000004e4c510>
```

It seems it isn't the Rails way to access the session from a model.

- **But why? Is it really that bad?**
- **And how can I access the session in the model?**
- **How is the above violating MVC? Is it because the model is changing something other than the database? And the model should only edit the
  database? Other than that it isn't violating MVC...**
- **Where then should this authentication machinery go? A private method in the sessions_controller?**

Comment: Why can't you pass the `remember_token` back with the method then do `session[:remember_token] = @user.sign_in`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why? Is it really that bad?
>
> And how can I access the session in the model?

*If you look at your error it clearly explain things*

> undefined local variable or method `session' for #

*You can't use session in Models simply because **session method is defined in [Action Controller](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#class-ActionController::Base-label-Sessions)** and since your controllers inherit from application controller so it's available in controllers*

> How is the above violating MVC? Is it because the model is changing something other than the database? And the model should only edit the database? Other than that it isn't violating MVC...

***Yeah you are right Models are for querying database and storing some value in session seems more like an action and this is what controllers are for.***

> Where then should this authentication machinery go? A private method in the sessions_controller?

As `@japed` suggested what you can do is return your remember_token from your method and then set it in controller like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by email: session_params[:email]
  if @user && @user.authenticate session_params[:password]
    session[:remember_token] = @user.sign_in
  end
end

def sign_in
  remember_token = self.generate_remember_token
  self.update_attributes remember_token: remember_token
  return remember_token
end
```